# How to switch between Docker related development and non-Docker related development?

Tags: memory, cpu, performance, bsod, docker

This is a copy of [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363360).

On my PC, I have a process "vmmem", eating up to 1.6Gb of RAM, and regularly using my entire CPU usage. After some investigation, based on several [`wmic process where (processid=PROCID_HERE) get parentprocessid`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486717/finding-parent-process-id-on-windows), I've found out that this is caused by a service, called "Hyper-V Host Compute Service".
Very naïvely, I've stopped that process (but as the RAM did not reduce, I decided to restart it again), resulting in the new version of "Blue Screen Of Death". Obviously I prefer not to see this screen :-)

I have Docker-Compose on my PC (hence the "Hyper-V" service), but apparently stopping the different containers also does not reduce the RAM usage.

Does anybody know what I can easily switch off/on in order to switch between Docker related development (needing the Docker containers) and other development (having enough spare RAM)?

**Edit**
My problem is that the process, called `vmmem`, takes a huge amount of memory, but I have no idea how this is built up: I can imagine some of it comes from the `Docker` process itself, some from the containers, again some others from the processes I'm running under the `Docker` environment, but when I stop the containers or my processes, this does not decrease the memory usage. Does anybody know what I can do in order to decrease the memory usage of the `vmmem` process?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSL 2 is based on a lightweight Linux VM that is running using Hyper-V technologies. The `vmmem` process is the running VM itself as visible from the host PC. All WSL 2 distributions (including the Docker Desktop distribution) share the same VM.

The VM will shut down a few minutes after you stopped using WSL 2. To shut down WSL (both 1 & 2) immediately, you can run `wsl --shutdown`. This will *immediately and without further prompts* kill any and all WSL processes, so make sure you don’t have any critical tasks running in WSL.

Keep in mind that the Docker Desktop application itself will keep WSL 2 active while it is running, even when no containers are running. If you don’t need Docker, exit Docker Desktop. Maybe also disable starting it automatically at logon.

---

How to develop using Docker or otherwise is specific to whatever you are doing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was a bit too fast to accept your answer (although it's quite useful): I've just done a `wsl --shutdown` and after a while (I don't know exactly what I did) I ended up again in a blue screen of death. Do you know the root cause for that problem?

Comment: No. Your Windows OS installation is most likely corrupted.

Comment: You're right: I've run `sfc /scannow` and some system files were corrupted indeed.

Comment: It’s unlikely this will solve the problem, but good luck! There are various questions about Windows corruption on Super User that could help.